# Php Video Played Percentage

Tags: php, javascript, video

Is there any html5 player that can let me know

- Whether user played a video
  For example if a user clicked play button on a specific video.
- Percentage of video played
  For example A user only plays 20% of video. If an video is 5mins long and user played only 1 minute before stopping the video or closing the browser

I am open to Ajax using PHP and other means of doing it which can be handled I googled and wasnt able to locate video player except [flv player](http://flv-player.net/players/js/)
I need few html5 player which have above functionality.

Comment: Since the video is played on the client, not the server, I fail to see how this has anything to do with PHP.

Comment: I want to keep a record like
if user has played video :- Video status (a thumbnail and status) changes to ALREADY PLAYED
If user has played only  part of video :- Play Again
need to update database with 0/1 as oer video played status

Comment: Any one who can enlighten me about such a player As per my question I did found a JS player http://flv-player.net/players/js/ but I am looking for a HTML5 video player that can do something similar to or can be tweaked to do similar

Answer (score 0):

I use "flowplayer" for many of my projects that require video. It has an HTML5 plugin, and it allows you attach a number of events (play, for example).

I would suggest attaching a function to the "onPlay" event that does an XHR to a PHP script that records a user playing a video. You can pass the SESSION and COOKIE user info to the script.

Vimeo also has a plugin called "Froogaloop" that might help you out if you want to use Vimeo as a CND.